# How to serve Angular data in production Spring BOOT?

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot

In every integration tutorial I've found (also tried searching docs) regarding Spring/BOOT with Angular (and often gradle) there is talking how to compile Angular for production and how to work with it in development.

I think everything I've found pointed to the fact that you run Server (Spring BOOT) on one port (default 8080) and Client (Angular) as development "ng serve" on second port (default 4200).

So basically in development this means you have 2 separate servers that don't even need to know about each other. In all the tutorials Angular uses Spring as REST JPA Repository (which concurs with previous sentence).

My problem is - everywhere i look to make them work together in dev, a trick is used, that looks somewhat like this:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/api"})
public class SomeController
```

So to make Spring allow Angular 4200 server to actually work, we set CrossOrigin to that port. While in dev its absolutely fine, then when we pack out Angular client for production there is no need for that annotation - isn't Spring supposed to be responsible for serving content from its port (8080)? There are no longer 2 servers, only one.

Finally my questions are:

What is correct approach here? Do I really need `@CrossOrigin` policy for it to work in dev? If so, can I remove this in production? Does Spring have some neat trick to mark it as "devOnly"?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48729208/1235935 .If both your server and Angular dev server run in localhost, you don't need any cross origin stuff

Answer (score 1):

Spring does have the `@Profile` annotation.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html
If you use for example, the "dev" profile on your local machine, you could use `@Profile("dev")` to only load a bean when your using the dev profile.
You probably don't want to annotate every single controller class with some configuration.
So create a configuration class where you can configure dev only stuff and annotate it with the `@Profile("dev")` annotation.